# Visual Studio doesnt recognise the namespace from library even tho frameworks are set correctly

Tags: visual-studio

I have 2 libraries in my project (one is "Core" and one is "Data")
I have a public class in my "core" library and I want it to connect it to a class in "data"
Core has 2.0 framework and Data has 2.1 framework.
Whenever I try to add a reference it says namespace not found. help please[image]

Comment: Try a capital `C` and add the missing semi-colon i.e. `using Core;`

Comment: Ive tried that too but doesnt work

printscr: http://prntscr.com/xdfjho

Comment: Have you added a reference from one project to another?

Comment: Have you added a project reference to Core?

Comment: yes whenever I try to do that it loads endlessly and then gives msg that a report has been sent to visual studio 

printscr: http://prntscr.com/xdfmp5

Comment: If I were you I would (and test every step to stop if worked):
1. Restart Visual Studio
2. Check your .proj
3. Change namespace to a trivial name that may not be a reserved word.

You have several projects, By names it seems you will reference from the App the project Data & Core, and from Data reference Core.
However I see you have an interface in Data and the concrete class in Core, may seems weird but it's your choice and has nothing to do with functionality.

Comment: Yeah ive tried literally everything ive updated to other frameworks.. tried changing namespaces and different libraries but nothing works, as for the interface in data thats how i was taught in school..